# How can I detect if datatable columns are currently being re-ordered

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am scraping products data from amazon, and I add a row each time a product is scraped.

But when I am re-ordering and at the same time a row is being added, I get a "column number is not the same" error, expected.

I am looking for something that will show me exactly when the table is being re-ordered.

I tried this:

```
  if (table.colReorder.order().length == 15) { // 15 is the number of columns
    $("table")
      .DataTable()
      .row.add($(productObjRowHtml(productObj)))
      .draw(); // add the product
  } else {
    setTimeout(addProduct, 1000, productObj, table); # wait and add it later
  }
```

But apparently while holding the column, the `table.colReorder.order()` is still giving me 15 items.

is there something I can use?

**Edit:**

A better code view:

```
var table = $("table").DataTable(tableDefinition);

function addProduct(ProductObj, table) {
  var tableColumnOrder = getTableColumnOrder(table)
  if (tableColumnOrder.length == 15) {
    $("table")
      .DataTable()
      .row.add($(productObjRowHtml(ProductObj)))
      .draw();
  } else {
    setTimeout(addProduct, 1000, ProductObj, table);
  }

}

function getTableColumnOrder(table) {
  var columnOrder = table.colReorder.order()
  return [...columnOrder]
}
```

Comment: column length is being changed? you've written that a new row is added. why column number is not the same error is coming?

Comment: @shubham ``table.colReorder.order().length`` is supposed to give me the column length, but it is not being changed while I am holding the columnd to re-order it